# Google Drive API ExtensionNotFound Error (Python)

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use the Google Drive and Google Sheets APIs with Python to access a test Google Sheet that I set up. Just following a tutorial online, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\...\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 131, in get_extension_for_class
    "No {} extension was found".format(extclass), extclass.oid

ExtensionNotFound: No <class 'cryptography.x509.extensions.SubjectAlternativeName'> extension was found
```

Suffice it to say, I'm pretty confused.

**Project Code:**

```
#import library
import gspread

#Service client credential from oauth2client
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

#Create scope
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

#create some credential using that scope and content of startup_funding.json
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json',scope)
#create gspread authorize using that credential
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

wks = client.open('api_tester').sheet1
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- Using pip to install the cryptography package, but it says everything is there
- Removing the `.sheet1`, which gets rid of the error but obviously doesn't help me achieve my goal

Is there something in that `.sheet1` method that's causing this, perhaps?

I'm using Python 3.7, I have the correct Sheet title and, as far as I can tell, all of the right permissions on my API credentials (I've also given Sheet edit access to the client_email in the JSON file).

I've never seen an error like this before and would really appreciate any help you can provide!

Edit:
**Here is the full traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-6114487ac5ae>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/parke/OneDrive/Documents/Random Projects/API injector.py', wdir='C:/Users/parke/OneDrive/Documents/Random Projects')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/parke/OneDrive/Documents/Random Projects/API injector.py", line 13, in <module>
    wks = client.open('api_tester').sheet1

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 73, in request
    headers=headers

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 355, in connect
    cert = self.sock.getpeercert()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 360, in getpeercert
    'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 211, in get_subj_alt_name
    x509.SubjectAlternativeName

  File "C:\Users\parke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 131, in get_extension_for_class
    "No {} extension was found".format(extclass), extclass.oid

ExtensionNotFound: No <class 'cryptography.x509.extensions.SubjectAlternativeName'> extension was found
```

Comment: What versions of Python do you have installed? There may be interpreter confusion.

Comment: @th0nk- Just checked with the cmd line and I'm running 3.7.3. I'm using Spyder which says '(Python 3.7)' above the toolbar. I've been running other Python programs (some calling other non-Google APIs) with no issue

Comment: Could you show the full traceback?

Comment: @th0nk- Updated the question with full traceback.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's a dependency issue then. The `SubjectAlternativeName` extension wasn't in older versions of the cryptography library, so you could be referencing old source. Are you familiar with using virtual environments?

Comment: @th0nk- Haven't done it before but I just pulled up some guides on it. What's your recommendation?

Comment: For ease of use, I'd recommend using poetry or pipenv, but run the program inside of a virtual environment so you can ensure all of the sources are up to date.